# How to set a buttons constraints equal to the safe area in Swift?

Tags: swift, uibutton, constraints, nslayoutconstraint

I have simple code for a UIButton:

```
let myButton = UIButton()
        myButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "cross"), for: .normal)
        myButton.tintColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)

        view.addSubview(myButton)
```

I would like to set the button so that it sits in the top left off the screen. I tried using the CGRect frame but that did not achieve what I wanted. I am trying to figure out how to have the left side of the button on the safe area and the top of the button on the safe area although I don't know how to do this. (I'm somewhat new to coding and have been using storyboards so...)

Answer (score 0):

Do some searching for Autolayout tutorials.

But, to get you started...

```
    let myButton = UIButton()
    myButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "cross"), for: .normal)
    myButton.tintColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
    myButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
    view.addSubview(myButton)
    
    let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        // constrain button 20-pts from top and leading
        myButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 20.0),
        myButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
    ])
```